# VBA fails to limit to just .dat files if there are zip files present in the folder

Tags: vba, filter, directory, zip

I have added a filter to the type of files allowed to selected (.dat files) however I have found that if there are zip files present in the folder the script does not work correctly as it also opens the zip files.

```html
'Specify folder where measurement files are stored
With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
    If .Show = True Then
    MyFolder = .SelectedItems(1)
    Else
        Exit Sub
    End If
End With

Sheet8.Columns.ClearContents

sFile_Name = Dir(MyFolder & "\*.dat*")
Do While sFile_Name <> ""
    Set wsData_Sheet = Sheet5
    j = wsData_Sheet.Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    jn = j + 1
    lcl = Sheet8.Cells(2, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    lclp = lcl + 1

    Call PARSE_MDF(MyFolder & "\" & sFile_Name, jn, sEND, lclp)
    sFile_Name = Dir()
Loop
```

How do I exclude zip files and limit it to only .dat files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm *guessing* that your zip files may also hold the string `.dat` somewhere in them (such as `file.dat.zip` for example) because this snippet:

```
sFile_Name = Dir(MyFolder & "\*.dat*")
'                    note this bit ^
```

will give you all files *containing* `.dat`, not all those *ending* in `.dat`.

If you only want the latter, try:

```
sFile_Name = Dir(MyFolder & "\*.dat")
```

(without the final `*`).